# Does Bran Stark know the truth about Littlefinger?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thrones* S07E04, Bran was talking with Litllefinger and it appeared that He knows the truth behind him.

The first question is does Bran know who really Littlefinger is?

The second question is while the two were talking Littlefinger mentioned the word Chaos, and Bran said it again and it appeared that Littlefinger sensed that Bran knows something about him.

What came into my mind is that this word if I must remember very well was used by Littlefinger when Ned Stark was surrounded and hurt in his knee in King's Landing when he was seeing his wife Lady Stark in Littlefinger's house.

Comment: `does Bran knows who really Littlefinger is?` - Does anyone (we) know who really Littlefinger is? Can't predict him, ever..!!

Comment: @TheCoder, if you can't predict him, at least you can know that he is not on your side, even if he helps you when you need him.

Comment: @TheCoder: **Of all people**, Bran is in the best position to know both Petyr's future and his past clandestine activities.

Comment: People need to realize that books have not been written so far that can give answers about what might happen in the show. The answers to such questions is purely speculative. I might suggest r/gameofthrones & r/asoiaf Reddit threads for such speculative questions. Sorry but -1

Comment: What is this truth you're talking about?

Comment: @PieterB, Don't tell me that during all seasons of game of thrones you did not had even at once a hint that tells you that there is something big behind Litllefinger and that he is friend of no one but himself, if he help you don't get it wrong and mekr him your firned because in the next chance when he is going to see your weakness he is going to use it against you and leave you behind. This is the kind of the truth i am talking about(he is friend of no one but himself)

Comment: @Mourad why I asked this, is that there are so many "truths" you could be talking about. The fact the he only thinks about himself, that he betrayed Eddard, that he killed his wife, that cersei granted him warden of the north, that he gave Ros to King Joffrey to be killed, that it possibly was Petyr who hired the assassin to kill Bran? And more and more and more.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

### Bran knows something..

Littlefinger says..

> "I imagine you've seen things most men wouldn't believe, to go through all of that and make your way home again only to find such chaos in the world, I can hardly imagine - "

Bran interrupts

> **"Chaos is a ladder"**

This is a shock to Littlefinger because Littlefinger himself had said in season 3, something Bran would have no way of knowing until he became the Three-Eyed Raven. In episode six of the the third season, when Littlefinger was serving Joffrey , he said this to Lord Varys:

> "The realm. Do you know what the realm is? It's the thousand blades of Aegon's enemies, a story we agree to tell each other over and over, until we forget that it's a lie."

Varys replied..

> "But what do we have left, once we abandon the lie? Chaos? A gaping pit waiting to swallow us all."

Littlefinger said.

> "Chaos isn't a pit, **Chaos is a ladder.** Many who try to climb it fail and never get to try again. The fall breaks them. And some, are given a chance to climb. They refuse, they cling to the realm or the gods or love. Illusions. Only the ladder is real. The climb is all there is."
>
> <sup>[Source](http://www.refinery29.uk/2017/08/166890/chaos-is-a-ladder-littlefinger-game-of-thrones)</sup>

<sup>Additional point mentioned by @Flater in a comment</sup>

> It seems relevant to mention that Petyr's quotes of "Chaos is a ladder" and "This dagger is Tyrion's" are separate events that took place in different places. Bran asked for confirmation whether Petyr knows whose dagger it is. But instead of stating that he knows what Petyr said to Cat about the dagger, he chooses a more subtle reference. **To Bran's mind**, he wanted to convey to Petyr that Bran is aware of everything (not just the dagger). Whether Petyr understands Bran's magical omniscience (compared to Bran having heard the "chaos is a ladder" quote from Varys) is unclear.

Comment: It seems relevant to mention that Petyr's quotes of "Chaos is a ladder" and "This dagger is Tyrion's" are separate events that took place in different places. Bran asked for confirmation whether Petyr knows whose dagger it is. But instead of stating that he knows what Petyr said to Cat about the dagger, he chooses a more subtle reference. **To Bran's mind**, he wanted to convey to Petyr that Bran is aware of **everything** (not just the dagger). Whether Petyr understands Bran's magical omniscience (compared to Bran having heard the "chaos is a ladder" quote from Varys) is unclear.

Comment: @Flater, yes this is too is a point of view that conerns this situation

Comment: "Bran knows something..." The new "You know nothing, Jon Snow"?

Answer (score 2):

In the last episode.

> It’s all pieces now, fragments, I need to learn to see better. When the Long Night comes again, I need to be ready.

I think Bran Still need to improve his Abilities. And he is focused on that.

And also he called himself three eyed raven now,and he might been thinking not to tell about the dagger or snow.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes.** According to an [interview of Isaac Hempstead Wright](http://www.makinggameofthrones.com/production-diary/isaac-hempstead-wright-on-the-fine-balance-of-playing-bran) (actor who plays Bran Stark / Three Eyed-Raven) in the [official Making Game of Thrones website](http://www.makinggameofthrones.com/production-diary/isaac-hempstead-wright-on-the-fine-balance-of-playing-bran) (emphasis mine):

> HBO: What’s Bran’s intention when he echoes Littlefinger’s own phrase,
>   “Chaos is a ladder”?
>
> Isaac Hempstead Wright: That was my favorite scene to film this
>   season. It was so neat to say something that cool. **The fact that Bran
>   heard that line means that he’s gone back and looked through Mr.
>   Baelish’s timeline.** His intention is to slightly rattle Littlefinger,
>   to say, in just a subtle, really creepy way, **“I know what you’re up
>   to.”**

“Chaos is a ladder” was first mentioned by Baelish to Varys in Season 3 Episode 6, “[The Climb](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/The_Climb)”: