# When does Bran Stark remember Jaime pushing him?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

I've just seen Jaime apologize to Bran for pushing him off the tower in *Game of Thrones*. When does Bran remember and how does Jaime discover Bran has remembered in the series?

Comment: I had assumed that Bran was lying about not remembering, to avoid having to explain what he saw and causing problems for his parents and potentially further attempts to murder him.

Comment: When does, or why would, he forget? And why would Jamie think he ever forgot?

Comment: @Mazura Jamie probably assumes that Bran forgot, or else why did Bran not tell anyone?

Comment: @Mazura I guess he assumed that the trauma of falling a long way and suffering life-changing injuries caused him to forget. People do sometimes forget the moments before a traumatic event.

Comment: Prior to walking into Winterfell, there was nothing anyone could or would have done about it. *A Lannister ate your baby, huh? Well, that's just too bad.* - I think *Jamie* forgot about it, otherwise he wouldn't have been caught flatfooted staring at him.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Since becoming the Three Eyed Raven, Bran has the ability to remember, well, everything that's ever happened in Westeros, including how he fell from the tower (although given that Sam was able to tell him some, ahem, surprising news, it seems that he doesn't just "know" everything in the past). Bran also has a habit of repeating things he never could have heard people say, just as a subtle way of saying *"just so you know, I know"*. As he throws Bran from the window, Jaime quips to Cersei, "The things I do for love". When Bran paraphrases this line back to Jaime while staring him in the eye in S8e2, it becomes clear to Jaime that Bran knows what happened.

He does something similar with Littlefinger, quoting "chaos is a ladder" at him, despite it being impossible for him to have heard the original conversation.

Comment: That's not true. Bran doesn't remember everything ever, he has the ability to witness things at will; but he doesn't know things he hasn't had cause to observe. In the books, he can observe it as long as it was in front of a weirwood, but I don't recall a weirwood being at the Tower of Joy.

Comment: A couple of points - I think Jaime says "the things I do for love" just *before* pushing Bran.  And I think the quote he gives to Littlefinger is "I told you not to trust me".  (Maybe he gives two...)

Comment: @AzorAhai It seemed to me that Bran has the ability to pretty much recall any event at will. I'm not saying he *has* watched all of Westeros' history play out, but he has the ability to remember any of it. Not sure that his ability is linked to the weirwoods in the show - he seems to view events that don't take place within sight of a weirwood.

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner Bran's quote "I told you not to trust me" was during Littlefinger's trial right before he died. "Chaos is a ladder" was divulged to Littlefinger [earlier](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/78479/does-bran-stark-know-the-truth-about-littlefinger/78481#78481).

Comment: @AzorAhai this is TV and Movie exchange -- I don't think him being limited to things that happened near a weirwood is relevant here.  Agreed that he doesn't "know" everything by default though, he has the ability to remember it but has to actually do so

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I just said.

Comment: @AzorAhai - There was no weirwood in the birthing room at the Tower of Joy (Jon/Aegon's birth), or outside the Tower of Joy (Ned's battle with Ser Dayne) nor was there one in the open area of Winterfell (Hodor becoming Hodor), or within the halls of the Red Keep (betrayal of Ned Stark), so nothing is contingent upon a weirwood tree witnessing it. The answerer isn't saying that Bran automatically knows everything, as much as has access to anything he wants. It would be absurd to think he wouldn't check on that event.

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner - When Bran first returns to Winterfell, and Littlefinger gives him the dagger, he blathers on about how awesome it was that Bran survived outside the wall and says "To go through all of that and make your way home again only to find such chaos in the world, I can hardly imagine - " when Bran hits him with his own personal tagline. He gives Bran a "WTF?" look, but then they are interrupted by Meera Reed coming in to tell Bran she's leaving to go home.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet "The answerer isn't saying that Bran automatically knows everything, as much as has access to anything he wants" I don't think the answer is clear on that, that's all.